# Unexpected value for the linker script variables

Tags: c, assembly, linker, linker-scripts

I am trying to write my own linker script.
The current version is here:

```
MEMORY
{
  ROM      (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
  RAM      (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x00004000, LENGTH = 0x00004000
}

STACK_SIZE  = 0x3000;
BOOT_PC     = 0x1000;

/* Section Definitions */
SECTIONS
{
  /* Code and constants */
  .text :
  {
    *(.rodata*);
    KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*));
    . = BOOT_PC;
    KEEP(*start.o(.text*));
    *(.text*);
    _etext = . ;
    _idata = . ;
  } > ROM

  /* Unitialized data */
  .bss (NOLOAD) :
  {
    _sbss = . ;
    *(.bss*);
    *(COMMON);
    _ebss = . ;
  } > RAM

  /* Initialized data */
  .data : AT(_idata)
  {
    _sdata = . ;
    *(.data*);
    _edata = . ;
  } > RAM 

  /* Stack */
  .stack (NOLOAD):
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    . = . + STACK_SIZE;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _stack = . ;
  } > RAM
}
```

In my C program, I have global variables which are supposed to go in .bss (foo) and .data(init, a1 and a2) sections:

```
int foo;

int init = 4;
int a1 = 4;
int a2 = 4;
```

When I use objdump, I have the following result:

```
elf/noste.elf:     file format elf32-littleriscv

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00004000 l    d  .sbss  00000000 .sbss
00004004 l    d  .sdata 00000000 .sdata
00004010 l    d  .stack 00000000 .stack
00000000 l    d  .comment   00000000 .comment
00000000 l    d  .riscv.attributes  00000000 .riscv.attributes
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 start.o
0000103c l       .text  00000000 _end_trigger
00001050 l       .text  00000000 _end_loop
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 main.c
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 reset.c
0000105c g     F .text  0000008c reset_handler
00003000 g       *ABS*  00000000 STACK_SIZE
000010e8 g       .text  00000000 _etext
00004000 g       .text  00000000 _sbss
00004008 g     O .sdata 00000004 a1
00004004 g       .sdata 00000000 _sdata
00004000 g       .text  00000000 _ebss
000010e8 g       .text  00000000 _idata
00001000 g       .text  00000000 _start
0000400c g     O .sdata 00000004 init
00001054 g     F .text  00000008 main
00004004 g     O .sdata 00000004 a2
00004000 g     O .sbss  00000004 foo
00004004 g       .sdata 00000000 _edata
0000103c g       .text  00000000 _end
00007010 g       .stack 00000000 _stack
00001000 g       *ABS*  00000000 BOOT_PC
```

As expected, the different C variables are placed in the .sbss and .sdata sections.
However, **_ebss** and **_edata** are not incremented and have the same value than _sbss and _sdata.
Instead of **_ebss** = 00004000 and **_edata** = 00004004, I expected **_ebss** = 00004004 and **_edata** = 00004010.
An idea about my issue here ?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but if your stuff is in `.sbss` why does your linker script reference `.bss` and `*(.bss*)`? Also, can you post section headers?

Comment: Between _sbss and _ebss, your linker script only puts .bss, but not .sbss.

Comment: I added the *(.sbss*) and *(.sdata*) and it seems to solve my issue. Finally, my misunderstanding comes from that .bss and .bss are not used here. I will search in the documentation of gcc more information about the different used sections, to ensure that I will not have more surprise. Thanks for your help!